# How Google play knows the country of app installation?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play, google-play-services

How do Google play knows the country where the user in when installing application from Google Play Store ?

**Edit:**
But the location persimmons are not used in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they use the network location from where the download is started. I can't think of a better alternative.

Comment: But the location persimmons are not used in the application.

Comment: It don't have to as it has nothing to do with the app. They are using the IP from which you start the download and check in which country this IP is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

While installing the application from play store, you need not to worry about permission used in application as google play uses its own permissions. And Google Play store used both i.e. network provider and GPS location to decide location of user. And based on that Google displays play store.

If you want to check play store for another country, you may use application like TunnelBear.